# Sidebar goes over footer when there's not enough space

Tags: html, css, footer, sidebar

When I make the browser window smaller or access it at a smaller resolution, the sidebar goes over the footer. Like on this page:

http://tithaty.com.br/?product_cat=mantas_peseiras

I've tried every suggestion I found here on the site, but nothing worked for me.

I works if I set the min-height of the floated div beside it "coluna_direita" to the height of the sidebar, but that's not ideal, since the sidebar might change heights if I add another category. So, is there a way to set the min-height of the "coluna_direita" div to change dynamically to whatever the height of the sidebar is?

Or any other easier solutions would be great.

Thank you

Edit: It's a custom Woocommerce template

```
<div class="wrap_shop">

<?php
/**
 * The Template for displaying product archives, including the main shop page     which is a post type archive.
 *
 * Override this template by copying it to yourtheme/woocommerce/archive-product.php
 *
 * @author      WooThemes
 * @package     WooCommerce/Templates
 * @version     2.0.0
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

get_header( 'shop' ); ?>


<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_before_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper - 10 (outputs opening divs for the content)
     * @hooked woocommerce_breadcrumb - 20
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content' );
?>


    <div id="coluna_direita">

    <div class="resultados">
    <?php
        /**
         * woocommerce_archive_description hook
         *
         * @hooked woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description - 10
         * @hooked woocommerce_product_archive_description - 10
         */
        do_action( 'woocommerce_archive_description' );
        ?>
        </div> <!--resultados-->

    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_before_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_result_count - 20
             * @hooked woocommerce_catalog_ordering - 30
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop' );
        ?>


        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_start(); ?>


            <?php woocommerce_product_subcategories(); ?>


            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>


                <?php wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' ); ?>

<?php /*<div id="desejos"><?php echo do_shortcode(   '[yith_wcwl_add_to_wishlist] ' ); ?></div> */ ?>
            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

        <?php woocommerce_product_loop_end(); ?>


        <?php
            /**
             * woocommerce_after_shop_loop hook
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_pagination - 10
             */
            do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop' );

        ?>

    <?php elseif ( ! woocommerce_product_subcategories( array( 'before' => woocommerce_product_loop_start( false ), 'after' => woocommerce_product_loop_end( false ) ) ) ) : ?>

        <?php wc_get_template( 'loop/no-products-found.php' ); ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_after_main_content hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end - 10 (outputs closing divs for the content)
     */
    do_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content' );
?>

</div> <! -- coluna_direita -->
<div id="sidebarshop">
    <div id="side_content">
<?php
    /**
     * woocommerce_sidebar hook
     *
     * @hooked woocommerce_get_sidebar - 10
     */
    /*do_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar' ); */
?>

<?php get_sidebar( 'shop' ); ?>
    </div> <!-- side_content-->
</div> <!-- sidebarshop -->
 <?php get_footer( 'shop' ); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The floats are causing the problem.

A solution that doesn't require changing the HTML structure:

```
#container {
    float: right;
    width: 75%;
}

#sidebarshop {
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    background-color: #fff;
    min-height: 100%; /** change from height to min-height **/
}

#coluna_direita {
    /* width: 75%; - moved to container */
    /* float: right;  - moved to container */
    padding-left: 20px;
    min-height: 100%; /** change from height to min-height **/
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

If you can change the HTML structure use flexbox:

HTML:

```
<div id="content" role="main">  

        <div id="sidebarshop"> <!-- move into #content -->
        </div>

        <div id="coluna_direita">
        </div>

</div>

#content {
    display: flex;
}

#sidebarshop {
    margin-top: -5px;
    width: 25%;
    /* float: left; - Remove the float **/
    background-color: #fff;
    /* height: 100%; - Remove the height, so the sidebar will push the flexbox down when needed **/
}

#coluna_direita {
    width: 75%;
    /* float: right; - Remove the float **/
    padding-left: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ori, here's the thing, this is a woocommerce template and I can't find the div content anywhere, I think it's inside a hook, so I can't move the sidebar divs inside it.

Comment: Added a solution that doesn't required changing the HTML structure.

Comment: I changed the 4000px to 100% and it worked, edit your answer, and thank you.

Comment: The 4000px was a leftover from my tests - it should be min-height: 100%. I updated the answer as well.